# How can I perform OAuth2 with OpenId

Tags: oauth, openid, oauth-2.0, hybrid

We want to do authentication and authorization with services Google provided on our website.
OAuth 1.0 can be combined to OpenId through OpenId Hybrid extension.
Can we achieve the same function for OAuth2.0? (do OAuth2 with OpenId authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OpenID Connect" will be what you need.
http://openidconnect.com/

It's basically OAuth2 and gives you OpenID identifier in access token response.
It also gives you an "profile attributes" API endpoint which is accessible using access token.

However, the spec is not ready to implement.
It'll take time, since OpenID community is always slow.